# UWP and azure-pipelines: Error CS1617: Invalid option '10' for /langversion

Tags: c#, azure-devops, uwp, azure-pipelines, c#-10.0

I have an UWP app and changed `<LangVersion>10</LangVersion>` inside .csproj to value 10. Everything works just fine (to my surprise).

But when I tried to build the app inside azure-pipelines it throws this error:

> ##[error]CSC(0,0): Error CS1617: Invalid option '10' for /langversion. Use '/langversion:?' to list supported values.

What is the last supported version of C# to be used in UWP app? How can I even test the `/langversion:?` command? (I really don't know where to put it). Why does it works perfectly fine on my local machine, but not inside azure-pipelines?

Target version: 19041, Minimal version: 17763

Comment: Try running on the `windows-2022` hosted image with visual studio 2022 as your visual studio version.

Comment: Assuming you are using microsoft-hosted build agent, you need the `windows-2022` agent to use `.net 6` and `c# 10`.

Comment: Well, that was it. Thanks. I had `windows-latest` and expecting to be the latest. That is a mystery to me - why the `windows-latest` is not pointing to 2022?